# Android permissions

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, android-permissions

For start I must say that I´m new to Android.

I´m a Msc Student and for my Msc thesis I've to develop a system that collects all user inputs on the touchscreen, regardless of the applications that are being used, and it must be done in background.

The objective is to use that data to establish a user profile and then apply an algorithm that continuously compare the new inputs with that old ones to grant the legitimate user authentication.

In other words I've to develop a touchlogger, but not for malicious purposes.

My question is: **Are the initial permissions, that a user accepts in the installation process, enough to allow my app to collect the touch inputs from other applications, or it will be blocked because of the sandbox?**

Note: The system is to be used for a regular person in a regular device, so rooting the device must not be an option.

Thanks for your help.

Best Regards

Comment: I really hope that it's not possible without root permission ;)

Comment: You don't have access to other apps. Not even to take a screenshot. You can only access what other access intentionally share (files, broadcasts, services, ...)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about spying / privacy breaking

Comment: Interesting question, I would think that it is somehow possible without root permissions by using a Service. The Facebook messenger chat heads function in such a way that they are able to overlay any activity that is currently running, I can't imagine it would be too difficult to abstract this concept to touch detection.

Comment: @KentHawkings: Those "chat heads" intercept and consume the touch events. As Raghav Sood's answer notes, consuming those touch events would prohibit the underlying apps from getting them, rendering the device useless. Such "tapjacking" attacks were possible on older versions of Android (1.x/2.x), but are no longer possible, thank heavens.

Comment: This would need to be deployed as part of a modified Android platform anyway (not just to read the events, but to be able to act on the authentication decision system-wide), so you should probably start with an AOSP build or one of the community ROM projects derived from it.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. @CommonsWare and what about RepetiTouch app by cygery? It records the touch inputs while using other applications and than you can repeat them. It has to be in a rooted device. I was looking for something like that to do the data collection, but without rooting.

Comment: "I was looking for something like that to do the data collection, but without rooting" -- fortunately, that is not possible, for privacy and security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, especially in newer versions of Android.

This is because even though there are system overlays allow you to display things like chat heads over any other app, you cannot capture touch events and pass them down to the app below. So even if you manage to capture the events, you will end up rendering the device useless, as nothing below your layover will work.